# Program reads in the contents of a file into an array, and display both the console and write to a file

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program that prompts the user for a file name.  I have to assume that the file contains an integer representing the number of n data values, followed by a series of n floating numbers(which was given to me in a file called RandomFloats), each written on a separate line. This program should read in the contents of the RandomFloats file into an array, and then both display in the console and write to a file the following data: the number of floating point numbers in the array, the lowest and highest number in the array, the total and the average. Here is my code so far(I will put in a comment at the part that is not working)

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.*;
 public class Problem9 {

/**
 * @param args 
 */
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    File rf = new File("RandomFloats");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(rf);  //Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException 
    double[] numFloats = new double [4268];
    for (int i = 0; i < numFloats.length; i++){
        numFloats[i] = kb.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a file name");
    String fileName = kb.nextLine();
    minValue (numFloats);
    maxValue (numFloats);
    totalValue (numFloats);
    averageValue (numFloats);

}
public static void minValue (double[] numFloats){
    double min = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numFloats.length; i++){
        if (numFloats[i] < min){
            min =  numFloats[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Min Value: " + min);
}
public static void maxValue (double[] numFloats){
    double max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numFloats.length; i++){
        if (numFloats[i] > max){
            max =  numFloats[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max Value: " + max);
}
public static void totalValue (double[] numFloats){
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFloats.length; i++){
        total += numFloats[i];
    }
    System.out.printf("\nTotal1: %.1f" , total);
}
public static void averageValue (double[] numFloats){
    double total = 0;
    double average;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFloats.length; i++){
        total += numFloats[i];
    }
    average = total / numFloats.length;

    System.out.printf("\nAverage: %.1f" , average);
}
    }
```

I am unsure how to print out the sample size and the file RandomFloats I created isnt being read into the array.  Please help me I am completely stuck, Thanks!!

Comment: `//Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException` Yep, the good old "File is not there or has different name situation". Where is the file?

Comment: The file is written under the JRE System Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception `FileNotFoundException` indicates that the file you specified was not found.  Perhaps it's not in the same directory that your program is executing in?  Perhaps it has some sort of suffix like `.txt`?  Try providing the fully qualified path to the file, like:

```
"/Users/bob.bobberton/RandomFloats"
```

Comment: Consider accepting this answer, or the other answer provided.  Whichever helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem starts with the line

```
File rf = new File("RandomFloats");
```

You're not passing a valid path to the File constructor, which is why the next line

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(rf);
```

is throwing a filenotfound exception

You should check out these links

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 0):

when you try to read a file, you need to provide it's extension so it is recognized as a file not a directory ... this happened to me several times

```
File rf = new File("RandomFloats.whatEver");
```